# PDFBox extracting paragraphs

Tags: pdfbox

I am new to pdfbox and I want to extract a paragraph that matches some particular words and I am able to extract the whole pdf to text(notepad) but I have no idea of how to extract particular paragraph to my java program. Can anyone help me with this atleast some tutorials or examples.Thank you so much

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Text in PDF documents is absolutely positioned. So instead of *words*, *lines* and *paragraphs*, one only has absolutely positioned *characters*.

Let's say you have a paragraph:

> Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit

Roughly speaking, in the PDF file it will be represented as characters `N` at some position, `e` a bit right to it, `q`, `u`, `e` more to the right, etc.

PDFBox tries to *guess* how the characters make words, lines and paragraphs. So it will look for a lot of characters at approximately same vertical position, for groups of characters that are near to each other and similar to try and find what you need. It does that by extracting the text from the entire page and then processing it character by character to create text (it can also try and extract text from just one rectangular area inside a page). See the appropriate class [PDFTextStripper](https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/2.0.3/javadocs/index.html?org/apache/pdfbox/text/PDFTextStripper.html) (or [PDFTextStripperByArea](https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/2.0.3/javadocs/index.html?org/apache/pdfbox/text/PDFTextStripperByArea.html)). For usage, see `ExtractText.java` in PDFBox sources.

That means that you cannot extract paragraphs easily using PDFBox. It also means that PDFBox can and sometimes will miss when extracting text (there are a lot of very different PDF documents out there).

What you *can* do is extract text from the entire page and then try and find your paragraph searching through that text. [Regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) are usually well suited for such tasks (available in Java either through [Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) and [Matcher](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) classes, or convenience methods on [String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) class).

Comment: Thank you so much. So I cannot use pdfbox for extracting a paragraph instead I need to use the generated text file to extract the paragraph using pattern matching. Thanks for the information.

Answer (score 3):

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws InvalidPasswordException, IOException {
    File file = new File("File Path");
    PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(file);        
    PDFTextStripper pdfStripper = new PDFTextStripper();
    pdfStripper.setParagraphStart("/t");
    pdfStripper.setSortByPosition(true);
    
    
    for (String line: pdfStripper.getText(document).split(pdfStripper.getParagraphStart()))
        {
            System.out.println(line);
            System.out.println("********************************************************************");
        }
}
```

Guys please try the above code. This works for sure with PDFBox-2.0.8 Jar

Comment: PDFBox includes some heuristics for guessing paragraph starts and ends. If one wants to retrieve paragraph starts and ends with a small error rate, using code like that indeed is the way to go. But remember, those are heuristics only, so there will be errors every so often...

Comment: I agree with you @mkl, it's just some heuristics. In fact I was working on developing advanced heuristics and ML techniques to determine headings, paras, tables, footers etc, (for our own PDFParser) but for an open source solution, PDFBox heuristics is the best

Comment: Indeed quite impressive.

Answer (score 1):

I had detected the start of paragraph using the using the following approach. Read the page line by line. For each line:-

1. Find the last index of '.' (period) in the line.
2. Compare this index with the length of the input line.
3. If the index is less then this implies that this is not the end of the previous paragraph.
4. If it is then it indicates that the previous paragraph has ended and the next line will be the beginning of the new paragraph.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I did split the text line by line and had additional requirements too but that was long back, thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

After extracting text, paragraph can be constructed programmatically considering following points:

1. All lines starts with small letters should be joined with previous line. But a line starts with capital letter may also require to join with previous line. e.g: for quoted expression.
2. .,?,!," ending line with these characters may be the end of paragraph. Not always.
3. If programmatically a paragraph is determined, then test it for even number of quotes. This may be simple double quote or Unicode double opening and closing quote.

Answer (score 0):

```java
private static String getParagraphs(String filePath, int linecount) throws IOException {
    ParagraphDetector paragraphDetector = new ParagraphDetector();
    StringBuilder extracted = new StringBuilder();
    LineIterator it = IOUtils.lineIterator(new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filePath)));
    int i = 0;
    String line;
    for (int lineNumber = 0; it.hasNext(); lineNumber++) {
        line = (String) it.next();
        if (lineNumber == linecount) {
            for (int j = 0; it.hasNext(); j++) {
                extracted.append((String) it.next());
            }
        }
    }
    return paragraphDetector.SentenceSplitter(extracted.toString());
}
```

Comment: Which **ParagraphDetector** class is that.

Comment: After finding specific word in file, it detects from starting point of word to end of the paragraph.

Comment: It is neither part of PDFBox not in the java standard API (or is it some newer addition?). Thus, from which library is it?

Answer (score 0):

You can first use pdfbox getText function to get the text. Every lines ends with '\n'; So you cannot segment paragraphs simpy with "\n". If a line satify the following condition:

`line.length() > 2 && (int)line.charAt(line.length()-2) == 32`

then this line is the last line of its paragraph. Here 32 is unicode value.

Comment: That works with very special PDFs only as it relies on a quirk of the PDF generator in question.

Comment: I know little about PDF generator. What kind of PDFs cannot be parsed in this way ? Could you please give some PDF examples? Thanks in advance.@mkl

Comment: I'll try and find an example when I'm back in office next week. But it clearly is a quirk of the software generating your pdfs to have a trailing space glyph in the last line of a paragraph. There is nothing in the pdf specification requiring that. (Actually that criterion surprises me, if pressed I would have thought the other way around to be more common. )

Comment: It's not urgent. So I will wait for you giving me PDF examples. Many thanks. (By the way, what does "that criterion" mean? I don't understand what surprise you. )

Comment: Essentially you claim that if a line ends with a space (before the '\n' end-of-line), *then this line is the last line of its paragraph*. But look at the copy of the ISO 32000-1 published by Adobe as [`PDF32000_2008.pdf`](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf), e.g. on page ii the situation is the other way around, all lines but the last line end with a space, only the last one does not! But there are exceptions to this, too, e.g. on page vii where "PDF/X" is split over two lines as "PDF/" and "X", there is no space after "PDF/".